How to use Cereal to deserialize Json array without surrounding object with key/value pairs
Let's say  we have an API that returns json reply in the form
[1,2,3]

According to json specification this is a valid Json. If I try to deserialize it to std::vector<int> using:
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/vector.hpp>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss("[1,2,3]");
    cereal::JSONInputArchive ar(ss);
    std::vector<int> vec;
    ar(vec);  // src/main.cpp:42  <-- here
    assert(vec.size() == 3);
    std::cout << vec[0] << ", " << vec[1] << ", " << vec[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

I get an exception:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cereal::RapidJSONException'
  what():  rapidjson internal assertion failure: IsObject()
Aborted (core dumped)

with stacktrace pointing to:
#0  0x00007ffff7e294a1 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0x000055555555a703 in rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::MemberBegin (this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/include/cereal/external/rapidjson/document.h:1168
#2  cereal::JSONInputArchive::startNode (this=0x7fffffffdc80)
    at /usr/local/include/cereal/archives/json.hpp:610
#3  0x00005555555567c8 in cereal::prologue<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, (cereal::traits::detail::sfinae)0> (ar=...) at /usr/local/include/cereal/archives/json.hpp:851
#4  cereal::InputArchive<cereal::JSONInputArchive, 0u>::process<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&> (head=std::vector of length 0, capacity 0, this=0x7fffffffdc80)
    at /usr/local/include/cereal/cereal.hpp:853
#5  cereal::InputArchive<cereal::JSONInputArchive, 0u>::operator()<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&> (this=0x7fffffffdc80) at /usr/local/include/cereal/cereal.hpp:730
#6  main () at /home/pptaszni/workspace/FooBar/src/main.cpp:42

Note that similar code where json has a key/value pair works fine:
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss{"{\"value0\":[1,2,3]}"};
    cereal::JSONInputArchive ar(ss);
    std::vector<int> vec;
    ar(cereal::make_nvp( "value0", vec));
    std::cout << vec.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << vec[0] << ", " << vec[1] << ", " << vec[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

How to deserialize Json string in the [1,2,3] form using Cereal?

hacky solution is to surround your json by stuff to make it a valid expected object: R"({"value0":%s)"

The construction of
cereal::JSONInputArchive ar(ss);

was successful, which means that underlying rapidjson::Document doesn't have a problem with this kind of json. This can be confirmed with:
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss{"[1,2,3]"};
    rapidjson::IStreamWrapper isw(ss);
    rapidjson::Document doc;
    doc.ParseStream<>(isw);
    assert(doc.IsArray());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < doc.Size(); i++) {
        std::cout << doc[i].GetInt() << std::endl;
    }
}

Stacktrace is pointing to class InputArchive method:
      //! Serializes data after calling prologue, then calls epilogue
      template <class T> inline
      void process( T && head )
      {
        prologue( *self, head );
        self->processImpl( head );
        epilogue( *self, head );
      }

which selects prologue( JSONOutputArchive & ar, T const & ) overload for "all other types for JSON archives", which apparently includes std::vector<int>. Then we hit the problematic code:
if(itsIteratorStack.back().value().IsArray())
  itsIteratorStack.emplace_back(itsIteratorStack.back().value().Begin(), itsIteratorStack.back().value().End());
else
  itsIteratorStack.emplace_back(itsIteratorStack.back().value().MemberBegin(), itsIteratorStack.back().value().MemberEnd());

which throw the exception, because our itsIteratorStack.back().value() is neither Array, nor Object. It is a Number.
Possible workaround for this problem is to provide empty implementations of prologue and epilogue functions, which are better overload candidates than templates in archives/json.hpp header:
namespace cereal {
void prologue(cereal::JSONInputArchive&, const std::vector<int>&){}
void epilogue(cereal::JSONInputArchive&, const std::vector<int>&){}
}

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss("[1,2,3]");
    cereal::JSONInputArchive ar(ss);
    std::vector<int> vec;
    ar(vec);
    assert(vec.size() == 3);
    std::cout << vec[0] << ", " << vec[1] << ", " << vec[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

Knowledge sharing inspired by this closed question and the answer for the problem with OutputArchive.
