Why am I getting "rapidjson internal assertion failure: IsArray()" error?
So I wanted to write the code for my mini game and need to read a json file for configuration of player. For this I used cereal library.
My code gave me an error, so I reduced it to simpler example but still got an error.
My code:
#include <cereal/types/map.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/string.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


struct Item {
    std::string name;
    int number;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar) {
        ar(cereal::make_nvp("name", name), cereal::make_nvp("number", number));
    }
};

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, Item> items;


    std::ifstream file("dataForTesting.json");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open the file!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    try {
        cereal::JSONInputArchive archive(file);

        archive(items);

    } catch (const cereal::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Error deserializing JSON: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "An error occurred: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }


    for (const auto& item : items) {
        std::cout << "Item ID: " << item.first 
                  << "\nName: " << item.second.name 
                  << "\nNumber: " << item.second.number << "\n" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


My json file:
{
    "item1": {
        "name": "Item One",
        "number": 1
    },
    "item2": {
        "name": "Item Two",
        "number": 2
    },
    "item3": {
        "name": "Item Three",
        "number": 3
    }
}

I compiled via $ c++ testingTesting.c++ -o test -std=c++11 -I. and executed via $ ./test and this is an error i got Error deserializing JSON: rapidjson internal assertion failure: IsArray()

"Why am I getting "rapidjson internal assertion failure: IsArray()" error?" Because the input data has the wrong format. cereal::JSONInputArchive "Input JSON should have been produced by the JSONOutputArchive. ... Only JSON originating from a JSONOutputArchive is officially supported, but data from other sources may work if properly formatted."

Could be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79163127/how-to-use-cereal-to-deserialize-json-array-without-surrounding-object-with-key/79163128#79163128 in principle, you are missing some top-level key. Take a look how cereal-serialized data would look like.

Based on example in documentation you are using wrong JSon format

Got it working with single item, but it fails with multiple items - I do not know why.

Basically you should check documentation of cereal! It explains how std::map is archived:
cereal Docs - Archive Specialization

Output using cereal built in support:
{
  "filter": [
    { "key": "type", "value": "sensor" },
    { "key": "status", "value": "critical" }
  ]
}


Note it archives data by explicitly stating "key" and "value". Rationale is that key for std::map do not have to be a std::string it can be anything and it should be serialized too. Note that in JSon key should be a string.
So by using default built in support for std::map you have to adjust your JSon:
{
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "item1",
            "value": {
                "name": "Item One",
                "number": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "item2",
            "value": {
                "name": "Item Two",
                "number": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "key": "item3",
            "value": {
                "name": "Item Three",
                "number": 3
            }
        }
    ]
}

Then it works.
Alternatively documentation provides an example how to alter this behavior. See section "Specializing the type".
Here is my attempt to use this appraoch:
#include <cereal/archives/json.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/map.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/string.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct Item {
    std::string name;
    int number;

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar)
    {
        ar(cereal::make_nvp("name", name), cereal::make_nvp("number", number));
    }
};

//! Loading for std::map<std::string, std::string> for text based archives
template <class Archive, class C, class A,
    cereal::traits::EnableIf<cereal::traits::is_text_archive<Archive>::value> = cereal::traits::sfinae>
inline void cereal::load(Archive& ar, std::map<std::string, Item, C, A>& map)
{
    map.clear();

    auto hint = map.begin();
    while (true) {
        const auto namePtr = ar.getNodeName();
        if (!namePtr)
            break;
        std::string key = namePtr;
        Item value;
        ar(value);
        hint = map.emplace_hint(hint, std::move(key), std::move(value));
    }
}

int main()
try {
    std::map<std::string, Item> items;

    cereal::JSONInputArchive archive(std::cin);
    archive(cereal::make_nvp("values", items));

    for (const auto& item : items) {
        std::cout << "Item ID: " << item.first
                  << "\nName: " << item.second.name
                  << "\nNumber: " << item.second.number << "\n"
                  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
} catch (const cereal::Exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "Error deserializing JSON: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
} catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

There is still extra level in JSon, but tweaking that I'm leaving for you.
